# "Type 'Any?' has no subscript members " error when trying to initialize objects from a nested JSON dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to simplify my code by removing as many nested dictionary values as possible.  My current custom object for JSON Data looks similar to this:

```
class JSONObject{

  var costDictionary: [String: Any]
  var airbnbDetails: [String: Any]
  var airbnbUS: Int
  var airbnbLocal: Int

 init(costDictionary: [String: Any], airbnbDetails: [String: Any], airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){
    self.costDictionary = costDictionary
    self.airbnbDetails = airbnbDetails
    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
}

 init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    costDictionary = (resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbDetails = (costDictionary["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbUS = (airbnbDetails["USD"] as? Int)!
    airbnbLocal = (airbnbDetails["CHF"] as? Int)!
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class JSONObject{

var airbnbUS: Int
var airbnbLocal: Int

 init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){
    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
}

init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){

airbnbUS = (resultsDictionary["cost"]["airbnb_median"]["USD"] as? Int)
airbnbLocal = (resultsDictionary["cost"]["airbnb_median"]["CHF"] as? Int)
}
```

Every time I try the bottom code I get a

> Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

error for "init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any])" portion of the 2 bottom "airbnbUS" and "airbnbLocal" values. Is there a way to make this error go away? If needed here is the function I use to update the object values:

```
static func updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: String, completion:
    @escaping (JSONObject?) -> Void) {

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

    _ = nm.getJSONData(urlExtension: urlExtension) {data in

      guard let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONFromData(data), let

        resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as?

        [[String : Any]] else {

          completion(nil)

          return
      }

      for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
        let jsonInfo = JSONObject(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

        completion(jsonInfo)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `resultsDictionary["cost"]` is understood as `Any?` not a dictionary, so you can't use just afterwards `["airbnb_median"]`. You need to tell the compiler that it's a dictionary. Same for the second call `["USD"]`. It doesn't know that  `resultsDictionary["cost"]["airbnb_median"]` is a dictionary. There a plenty of questions on SO about that error, did you read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultsDictionary["cost"]` is of type `Any`. You need to cast it to `[String:Any]` so that the compiler understands it is another dictionary. Try this:

```
init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    guard let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
        let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any],
        let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int,
        let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int else {
            //handle bad values
            airbnbUS = 0
            airbnbLocal = 0
            return
    }

    airbnbUS = usd
    airbnbLocal = chf
}
```

Or another way:

```
init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    guard let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
        let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any] else {
            //handle bad values
            airbnbUS = 0
            airbnbLocal = 0
            return
    }

    if let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int {
        airbnbUS = usd
    } else {
        //handle bad USD
        airbnbUS = 0
    }

    if let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int {
        airbnbLocal = chf
    } else {
        //handle bad CHF
        airbnbLocal = 0
    }
}
```

The first one sets both `airbnbUS` and `airbnbLocal` to `0` if there is an issue. The second will only set each property to `0` if it can't find the value for that individual property in the dictionary.